# Android - Service starts automatically every time I run my app in spite of I stop it

Tags: java, android, mobile, service

I have a service that only must run when the app is not running. I start it when the user close the app and I stop it when the user open the app.
When I install the app, the service starts immediately if I close the app, that is ok. When I open the app, the service stops (I can see the onDestroy method from the service called) but immediately and automatically starts again, without any instruction.

In my AndroidManifest.xml I have:

```
<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" android:exported="false">
 <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
 </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyService" />
```

That is 'cause I need start the service when the device was rebooted

And in my services I have

```
public class MyService extends Service {
Thread _thisThread=null;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
//code to execute when the service is first created

}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
//code to execute when the service is shutting down
 Log.v("App","MyService - OnDestroy method called");
}
@Override    
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {          

    Log.v("App","MyService - onStartCommand");

    //return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

Sincerely, I can't understand why the service starts automatically if I stop it.

Comment: on create runs everytime you open the app.

Comment: Even if I stop the service when I start the app?

Comment: START_STICKY will try re-create the service with a null intent if it is killed.

Comment: Yes, but using START_NOT_STICKY I have the same problem.